# Eclipse Project Explorer show modifications on SVN externals

Tags: eclipse, svn, external

I have project which contains source files and cmake file that creates deeper structure and download another sources from externals. The goal is to see in Project Explorer if any versioned file was modified. It is working fine for files on main repository, but not on externals.

Example:
Let's assume that we have directory *`General`* and code `main.cpp`. When i change `main.cpp`, icon in project explorer will change. Inside *`General`* cmake creates directory *`External`* and download external *`external.cpp`*. When i change this file, Eclipse doesn't show icon that file was modified on directory and file.

I've downloaded Subversive and try to change settings, but nothing helped. I am almost sure that there is a way to have this, but no idea how to set it.

Using IAR it is simple `Connect Project to subversion`, but it shows **only files**, so you have to expand all groups in explorer to see which files was modified...

Comment: If you do a _Refresh (F5)_ in the _Project Explorer_ view, do the changes become visible?

Comment: Unfortunately not, On each directory and file from external I see question mark sign (untracked)

Comment: I don't understand your question yet. If the files/folders are created by `cmake` and are not versioned/tracked, how can one know that they have been changed manually? From SVN's point of view, these are new and not yet committed files/folders within a versioned/tracked folder. Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: when you checkout the project, you have full repository (versioned, eclipse show status on every file). When you run cmake to download files from external repositories and put them inside those project (in directory Externals for example), TortoiseSVN doesn't see that those files are versioned until you go inside this directory. I mean when you go there (directory where externals were downloaded) and click "Check for modifications" you will see them, but on upper level you don't. It is more clear for you or I need to precise more? Anyway, thanks for being interested

Comment: Are the files/folders copied from the external repositories with or without the `.svn` subfolders?

Comment: with .svn subfolders.

Comment: In SVN it is not allowed to mix working copies of repositories this way. Maybe you can do it using the [`svn:externals` property](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html). But I don't have any experience with that. I have experience with accidentally copied `.svn` folders and I learned it is better not to do it.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to create project using main repository and put externals in the same directory, and have possibility to check changes in whole project? Project need particular structure, so it would be better to not change folder tree

Comment: `cmake` could work on a copy of the `External` folder that is ignored in the main SVN repository and that does not contain the `.svn` subfolders. A separate project would be needed to track `External`'s changes. But this would only work if no changes will be made in the copy that should be committed back into the `External` repository.